# md5sum of certain files in two different folders in bash

Tags: bash, md5sum, filelist

I want to copy files from folderA to folderB, where some of the copied files are written over existing files in folderB. folderB also contains files, which are not in folderA. After the operation I want to compare the md5sum of all the copied files in folders A and B.

How can I produce a list of files in folderA and pipe it to md5sum in folderB?
I tried:

```
 ls -1 | md5sum
```

but 'ls -1' is not a list of different files for md5sum...

Many thanks

Comment: More descriptions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to generate the md5sum of the files in folderA and the equivalent files in folderB:

```
cd folderA
md5sum *
cd folderB
( cd folderA && ls ) | xargs md5sum
```

However you might want to look at `diff` instead to check. And maybe `rsync` for doing the copying.

Comment: What I'm really doing is copying the files over a network connection to folderB and I wanna see if the changed files are exactly as in folderA, so the copying over network went fine. Actually already using rsync

Comment: If you are doing it over a network, you might want to do the checksum of folderA on the original machine, otherwise you are just comparing two copies over the network.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I wanna do: compare folderA on the original machine and folderB in the remote machine after rsync has done its job. Therefore I wanted a listing of folderA files on the original machine to save to a variable and then run md5sum for that list of files on the remote machine in folderB.

Comment: 'xargs' is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It should be reversely: `ls | md5sum`.

But that will compare only the file names. Is that what you really want?

If you want sums of all the contents of all the files, do for example `cat * | md5sum`.